# Dockerize Angular cli application in a remote server

Tags: angular, docker, centos, command-line-interface

i am trying to dockerize my angular app and i am getting an error("sh: 1: ng: Permission denied") when i am running the container. More specific my dockerfile is

```
   # Create image based on the official Node 6 image from dockerhub
   FROM node:8.10.0

   # Create a directory where our app will be placed
   RUN mkdir -p /app

   # Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
   WORKDIR /app

   # Copy dependency definitions
   COPY package.json /app

   # Install dependecies
   RUN npm install

   # Get all the code needed to run the app
   COPY . /app

   # Expose the port the app runs in
   EXPOSE 4200

   # Serve the app
   CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Firstly i create docker image successfully but when i am going to run it i am getting the error above.

[image]

The docker running to a remote server with centos operating system.The simple solution i think is to change the rights of start script but i dont know how i can do that.I will appreciate anything help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution ,just add to Dockerfile the lines below

```
 Run chmod 775 app/node_modules/.bin/ng

 Run chmod 775 app/node_modules/.bin/ng.cmd
```

The error occurs because i didnt gave permission to theese scripts.

Comment: Were you able to get your app to run? I am able to have my app start but when I go to the localhost of the server with port 4200 I get a "refused to connect error".

Answer (score 1):

I was able to launch the app after adding below two steps to `Dockerfile`:

1. `RUN npm install -g angular/cli`
2. `CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`

Final `Dockerfile` looks like below:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /App
WORKDIR /App
COPY . /App
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`
```

How to build docker file?

```
docker build --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t <tag_name> .
```

How to run docker image?

```
docker run -p 4200:4200 <image_id>
```